# .zshrc doesn't export variable for anaconda

Tags: macos, bash, python, zsh

I installed Anaconda Python on my Mac today and following line was added to .bash_profile by Anaconda. Since I am using zsh so I moved this line to .zshrc. However, it doesn't work properly even if I source .zshrc in iTerm.

```
export PATH="/Users/shawn/Softfolder/anaconda/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

If I move that line to .bash_profile and source it, Anaconda works as expected.

I am wondering does Anaconda work in that way or I did something wrong?
Many thanks!

More: I found following line in .zshrc below the line I added for anaconda. Is this line overridden the path for anaconda?

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin"
```

PS: I used

```
bash -l
```

to start a login session of bash then anaconda does work.

Comment: What does echo $PATH give you?

Comment: Also, you should use .zshenv for environment variables.

Comment: @Qudit it gives "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin"

Answer (score 0):

anaconda USES BASH so short of you running

> sudo chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh $username

FIRST it will not  look in ~/.zshrc as zsh is installed but not running

Comment: Thanks. I started a bash login session and it works. May I know how the chsh works in your answer? It runs the zsh session?